# Is it possible to get all Spell Lantern Upgrades?

Tags: legend-of-fae

I've just started playing *Legend of Fae* and I'm trying to figure out which path I want to take in regards to the Spell Lantern Upgrades. However, I have no idea how many parts total I'll end up getting in the game. I don't want to end up with a less effective build because I've split my upgrades across 2 or more paths or the like. There *does* seem to be a Reset ability, but it also says it will cost one of my total spare parts in order to use.

[image: Legend of Fae upgrade path]

I can hover over each locked item and it will tell me the cost, but I'm unsure if spare parts are something that I can end up grinding for or if there is a fixed amount of spare parts you can get in any given playthrough. Can I unlock the entire Spell Lantern, or will I be forced to choose a specific path?

Comment: I tried replaying an older level and didn't get any more parts... not a good sign.  Won't know for sure until one of us finishes the game, though.

Answer (score 1):

Just finished it myself, easy/casual mode. No, it's not possible to collect all the parts. I made sure I gathered a gear with each level, and here's how far I progressed by the end of the game:

[image]

If I'm counting correctly, that's 40 spare parts in total. Plan accordingly!